# How Do I Async Parallel Multiple app.use Calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ibm-cloud

How do I async parallel multiple app.use calls? I've read https://github.com/caolan/async and I've seen:

```
async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);
```

But I'm not quite sure how to use it with the following:

```
app.use('/api/users', api.users);
app.use('/api/score', api.score);
app.use('/api/payment', api.payment);
app.use('/api/ci',api.ci);
app.use('/api/db', api.concepts);
app.use('/api/swing', api.swing);
app.use('/api/list', api.list);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.use('/api/users', api.users)` is not an asynchronous code. It just assign `api.users` to handle request with paths matching `/api/users`. You don't need to use `async.parallel` for this.